# UML - Utilização do include e extend

Tags: uml

Estou montando um UML como estudo de caso e encontrei dúvidas na hora de montar.

Primeiro caso:

O primeiro exercício informa que existem dois atores: o aluno e a secretária sendo que esse aluno pede informações a secretária sobre quais palestras a empresa oferece. Caso o aluno se interesse por alguma delas, vai pedir informações como: quais seriam os horários, a data, o nome do palestrante.

Caso seja de agrado do aluno, ele ira realizar uma inscrição na palestra que ele se interessou. Caso ele nunca tenha participado de nenhuma palestra da empresa, sendo assim, não é cadastrado, deverá ser registrado na empresa antes de realizar a inscrição.

Assim, então pelo meu raciocínio:

O aluno vai solicitar informações a secretaria (relacionamento de comunicação);

Vai então verificar os temas e isso seria um extend de solicitar informações já que preciso solicitar antes, certo? E ele não é obrigado a verificar o tema. Entra na questão do "caso queira"

Assim, vai realizar a inscrição nesse tema. **Isso seria um extend apenas do tema ou preciso puxar do aluno?** Penso que não se puxa do aluno pois para se inscrever em algo preciso antes verificar. Isso que estou agarrando ainda...

Mas seguindo: dai teria um include de fazer inscrição -> manter registro pois é obrigatório o registro. **Eu posso só deixar ele como include ou no caso deveria puxar um relacionamento de aluno?**

Segundo caso:

Agora preciso fazer um sistema de vendas pela web

O usuário informará a cidade e o aeroporto que irá partir e o local desejado de destino. Isso informando se a passagem é só de ida ou com volta.

A partir dai, o usuário vai verificar se as opções que aparecem irão agradar ele. Se sim,  deve clicar em comprar as passagens e vai escolher como pagar.

O exercício fala que o usuário interage diretamente com a página da web. Preciso por essa página web como ator ou não?